# fill in missing value based on the nearest record

Tags: python

I want to update the missing values in the 'name' column by matching the 'type' and 'item' columns with the nearest 'created_dt' record. I'm seeking guidance on how to accomplish this using a Python script.

below is the input and expected output

input:

| item | type | name | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| a | 1 |  | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| b | 1 | cat | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| c | 1 |  | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| a | 2 | tiff | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| d | 2 |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |
| a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| c | 2 | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |

output

| item | type | name | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| b | 1 | cat | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| c | 1 |  | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| a | 2 | tiff | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| d | 2 |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |
| a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| c | 2 | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |

Comment: Are you using Pandas? If so, please [edit] and add the tag for it. BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```py
import pandas as pd


def fill_nearest_dt(grp: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Fills NaNs in the 'name' column with the nearest non-null value based on 'created_dt'.

    This function iterates over a DataFrame with missing 'name' values.
    For each missing 'name', it finds the 'created_dt' of the nearest non-null 'name'
    and fills the missing 'name' with this value.

    Parameters
    ----------
    grp : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with columns 'name' (possibly containing NaNs) and 'created_dt'.

    Returns
    -------
    grp : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with filled NaNs in the 'name' column based on the nearest 'created_dt'.

    Notes
    -----
    The function breaks if there are no non-null 'name' values in the DataFrame 'grp'.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> data = {
    ...     'item': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
    ...     'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    ...     'name': ['bb', None, 'cat', None, 'tiff', None, 'ali', 'don', None, 'ali'],
    ...     'created_dt': pd.to_datetime([
    ...         '2023-06-01 21:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 23:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 11:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 23:30:00',
    ...         '2023-06-06 09:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 00:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 19:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 18:00:00',
    ...     ])
    ... }
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    >>> df.groupby(['item', 'type'], group_keys=False).apply(fill_nearest_dt)
      item  type  name          created_dt
    9    a     1   ali 2023-06-01 18:00:00
    8    a     1   ali 2023-06-01 19:00:00
    0    a     1    bb 2023-06-01 21:00:00
    1    a     1    bb 2023-06-01 23:00:00
    6    a     1   ali 2023-06-02 03:00:00
    4    a     2  tiff 2023-06-01 23:30:00
    2    b     1   cat 2023-06-01 11:00:00
    3    c     1  None 2023-06-02 01:00:00
    7    c     2   don 2023-06-02 01:00:00
    5    d     2  None 2023-06-06 09:00:00
    """
    grp['_created_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(grp['created_dt'], errors='coerce')
    for idx, row in grp[grp['name'].isna()].iterrows():
        non_null_dt = grp[(grp['name'].notnull()) & (grp['_created_dt'].notnull())]['created_dt']
        if non_null_dt.empty:
            break
        grp.loc[grp.index.isin([idx]), 'name'] = grp.loc[
            grp.index.isin([(non_null_dt - row['created_dt']).dt.total_seconds().abs().idxmin()]),
            'name'
        ].values[0]
    
    return grp.drop(columns=['_created_dt'])


data = {
    'item': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
    'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    'name': ['bb', None, 'cat', None, 'tiff', None, 'ali', 'don', None, 'ali'],
    'created_dt': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-06-01 21:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 23:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 11:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 23:30:00',
        '2023-06-06 09:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 00:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 19:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 18:00:00',
    ])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=['item', 'type', 'created_dt'], inplace=True)
final_df = df.groupby(['item', 'type'], group_keys=False).apply(fill_nearest_dt)
final_df
```

**Input:**

|  | item | type | name | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-01 18:00:00 |
| 8 | a | 1 |  | 2023-06-01 19:00:00 |
| 0 | a | 1 | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| 1 | a | 1 |  | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| 6 | a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-02 03:00:00 |
| 4 | a | 2 | tiff | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| 2 | b | 1 | cat | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | c | 1 |  | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 7 | c | 2 | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 5 | d | 2 |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |

**Output:**

|  | item | type | name | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-01 18:00:00 |
| 8 | a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-01 19:00:00 |
| 0 | a | 1 | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| 1 | a | 1 | bb | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| 6 | a | 1 | ali | 2023-06-02 03:00:00 |
| 4 | a | 2 | tiff | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| 2 | b | 1 | cat | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | c | 1 |  | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 7 | c | 2 | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 5 | d | 2 |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |

### Edit: Adapting original code to work with multiple columns

If you have multiple columns with missing values you want to fill, you can add an additional parameter to `fill_nearest_dt`, that allows you to specify the names of the columns to fill.

For each of these columns, we can apply the same logic as before, making slight modifications to `fill_nearest_dt`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List

import pandas as pd


def fill_nearest_dt(grp: pd.DataFrame, columns: str | List[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Fills NaNs in columns with the nearest non-null value based on 'created_dt'.

    This function iterates over a DataFrame with columns tha have missing values.
    For missing values in each column specified, it finds the 'created_dt' of the
    nearest non-null value for the column to be filled and fills its missing values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    grp : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with column 'created_dt' and the names of the columns you specify.
    columns : str | List[str]
        Column or list of columns to fill NaNs with the nearest non-null value based on 'created_dt'.

    Returns
    -------
    grp : pd.DataFrame
        DataFrame with filled NaNs based on the nearest 'created_dt'.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> data = {
    ...     'item': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
    ...     'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    ...     'name': ['bb', None, 'cat', None, 'tiff', None, 'ali', 'don', None, 'ali'],
    ...     'name_2': ['bb', 'ali', None, 'tiff', None, None, 'ali', 'don', 'ali', None],
    ...     'created_dt': pd.to_datetime([
    ...         '2023-06-01 21:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 23:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 11:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 23:30:00',
    ...         '2023-06-06 09:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 00:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 19:00:00',
    ...         '2023-06-01 18:00:00',
    ...     ])
    ... }
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    >>> df.groupby(['item', 'type'], group_keys=False).apply(fill_nearest_dt, columns=['name', 'name_2'])
      item  type  name name_2          created_dt
    9    a     1   ali    ali 2023-06-01 18:00:00
    8    a     1   ali    ali 2023-06-01 19:00:00
    0    a     1    bb     bb 2023-06-01 21:00:00
    1    a     1   ali    ali 2023-06-01 23:00:00
    6    a     1   ali    ali 2023-06-02 00:00:00
    4    a     2  tiff   None 2023-06-01 23:30:00
    2    b     1   cat   None 2023-06-01 11:00:00
    3    c     1  None   tiff 2023-06-02 01:00:00
    7    c     2   don    don 2023-06-02 01:00:00
    5    d     2  None   None 2023-06-06 09:00:00
    """
    columns = [columns] if isinstance(columns, str) else columns
    grp['_created_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(grp['created_dt'], errors='coerce')

    for idx, row in grp[grp[columns].isna().any(axis=1)].iterrows():
        for column in columns:
            non_null_dt = grp[(grp[column].notnull()) & (grp['_created_dt'].notnull())]['created_dt']
            if non_null_dt.empty:
                continue
            grp.loc[grp.index.isin([idx]), column] = grp.loc[
                grp.index.isin([(non_null_dt - row['created_dt']).dt.total_seconds().abs().idxmin()]),
                column
            ].values[0]
    return grp.drop(columns=['_created_dt'])
```

Now you can fill missing values based on the nearest record to multiple columns, like so:

```py
data = {
    'item': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
    'type': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    'name': ['bb', None, 'cat', None, 'tiff', None, 'ali', 'don', None, 'ali'],
    'name_2': ['bb', 'ali', None, 'tiff', None, None, 'ali', 'don', 'ali', None],
    'created_dt': pd.to_datetime([
        '2023-06-01 21:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 23:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 11:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 23:30:00',
        '2023-06-06 09:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 00:00:00',
        '2023-06-02 01:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 19:00:00',
        '2023-06-01 18:00:00',
    ])
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=['item', 'type', 'created_dt'], inplace=True)
final_df = df.groupby(['item', 'type'], group_keys=False).apply(fill_nearest_dt, columns=['name', 'name_2'])
```

**Input:**

|  | item | type | name | name_2 | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | a | 1 | ali |  | 2023-06-01 18:00:00 |
| 8 | a | 1 |  | ali | 2023-06-01 19:00:00 |
| 0 | a | 1 | bb | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| 1 | a | 1 |  | ali | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| 6 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | a | 2 | tiff |  | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| 2 | b | 1 | cat |  | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | c | 1 |  | tiff | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 7 | c | 2 | don | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 5 | d | 2 |  |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |

**Output:**

|  | item | type | name | name_2 | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-01 18:00:00 |
| 8 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-01 19:00:00 |
| 0 | a | 1 | bb | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| 1 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| 6 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | a | 2 | tiff |  | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| 2 | b | 1 | cat |  | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | c | 1 |  | tiff | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 7 | c | 2 | don | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 5 | d | 2 |  |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |

Note that the function still works even if you use a single column name (string) as the `columns` parameter:

```py
final_df = df.groupby(['item', 'type'], group_keys=False).apply(fill_nearest_dt, columns='name')
final_df
```

**Output:**

|  | item | type | name | name_2 | created_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | a | 1 | ali |  | 2023-06-01 18:00:00 |
| 8 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-01 19:00:00 |
| 0 | a | 1 | bb | bb | 2023-06-01 21:00:00 |
| 1 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-01 23:00:00 |
| 6 | a | 1 | ali | ali | 2023-06-02 00:00:00 |
| 4 | a | 2 | tiff |  | 2023-06-01 23:30:00 |
| 2 | b | 1 | cat |  | 2023-06-01 11:00:00 |
| 3 | c | 1 |  | tiff | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 7 | c | 2 | don | don | 2023-06-02 01:00:00 |
| 5 | d | 2 |  |  | 2023-06-06 09:00:00 |

Comment: yes, it is working, if i have multiple columns to fill in the missing value, is there any way to simplify it, instead of duplicate the same function multiple times.

Comment: @Lee I've edited my original answer, and included a version of `fill_nearest_dt` that also works with multiple columns